# Put text on top div that is inside another div

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

I want to put the text over the div that is containing an image and that div is inside another div that also has an image.

```css
.marioHeader {
  background-image: url("resources/marioBackground.jpg");
  background-size: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  background-position: bottom;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-color: #6096ff;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
}

.headermario {
  background-image: url("resources/banner.png");
  background-size: 600px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="marioHeader">
  <h1 class="title">Super Mario</h1>
  <div class="headermario">
  </div>
</div>
```

It looks like this: [image]

I want it to look like this: [image]

Comment: `flex-direction: column;`

Answer (score 1):

You are using `flexbox` and flexbox comes as default `row`, you should change direction to column with `flex-direction: column`

```css
.marioHeader {
  background-image: url("resources/marioBackground.jpg");
  background-size: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  background-position: bottom;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-color: #6096ff;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
}

.headermario {
  background-image: url("resources/banner.png");
  background-size: 600px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="marioHeader">
  <h1 class="title">Super Mario</h1>
  <div class="headermario">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code:

```css
    .marioHeader {
      background-image: url("resources/marioBackground.jpg");
      background-size: 600px;
      height: 500px;
      background-position: bottom;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      background-repeat: repeat-x;
      background-color: #6096ff;
      margin-top: 50px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .title {
      text-align: center;
    }

    .headermario {
      background-image: url("resources/banner.png");
      background-size: 600px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: bottom;
      background-color: red;
      height: 200px;
      width: 90%;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="marioHeader">
      <h1 class="title">Super Mario</h1>
      <div class="headermario">
      </div>
    </div>
```